# How to re-use jQuery UI Dialog by changing dialog options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I know the correct way to manage JQuery.dialog is to initialize with:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

Then use the following to open and close it:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
```

But there are some cases when this model is not fully applicable.

For instance, I use a dialog to create new data and to edit existing data. In the first case I have a *cancel* and a *create* button, but in the second case I have also a *delete* button.

I've seen that there is a destroy function in jquery.dialog. The question is: in these cases, should I destroy the dialog instead of close it and create a new one? There is any better option?

Comment: If I get you right: why don't you just instantiate 2 dialogs?

Comment: Where do the buttons come from?

Comment: @m90: because it is a very complex dialog and just change in minimum details, like the buttons or that one dialog is pre-filled and other not. But initialize two dialogs is another option, of course.

Comment: @SalmanA: From the initialization parameters. There is a buttons parameters where you can set the buttons you need and the associated function.

Comment: You can manipulate the buttons *after* initialization. Will that be OK?

Comment: Not exactly, but it could work for me in this case. But I'm seeking for a more general case, something like destroy and create it again or don't destroy and check if it already exist before call to open or create function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI dialog allows you to manipulate most properties after initialization. You *can* change the buttons some time after the dialog is initialized; e.g. when the insert or update button is clicked.

```js
// imported from http://jsfiddle.net/salman/VYAJw/9/

$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
  });
  $("#button-insert").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("option", "title", 'Insert Record');
    $("#dialog1").dialog("option", "buttons", [{
      text: "Insert",
      click: function() {
        alert("Record inserted");
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]);
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
  });
  $("#button-update").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("option", "title", 'Update Record');
    $("#dialog1").dialog("option", "buttons", [{
      text: "Update",
      click: function() {
        alert("Record updated");
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Delete",
      click: function() {
        alert("Record deleted");
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]);
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.min.css");
body {
  font: medium sans-serif;
}

#dialog1 label,
#dialog1 input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog1">
  <p>Fill out this form.</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button-insert" value="Insert" />
<input type="button" id="button-update" value="Update" />
```

An alternate method would be to add the buttons directly inside the form and `.hide()` them depending on whether you're showing insert or update dialog.

Answer (score 2):

you can set different buttons as option before dialog open

e.g.

```
var  buttons = {
        "act_add": {
        "Insert": function() { ... },
        "Cancel": function() { ... }
        },
        "act_edit": {
        "Save": function() { ... },
        "Delete": function() { ... }
        }
      };

    $('.dialogOpenLink').click(function(){
      var $dlg = $('#dialog'),
      actType;

      //get an action name from data attribute of the clicked element
      actType = $(this).data('action'); //or get the action in way that best suits you

      $dlg.dialog( "option", "buttons", buttons[actType]);
      $dlg.dialog('open');
    });
```

Comment: P.S.: change title $dialog.dialog('option', {'title': newTitle});

Comment: var $dContent = $dialog.find('p'); $dContent.html('<span>new content</span>');

Answer (score 0):

To safelly remove dialog all you need is to set close option like this:

```
close: function() {
 return $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: This closes and removes the dialog, but... you cannot open it never more!! :)

Comment: Sorry. Probably I didn't get it right you want to remember options or html to be able to modify it? In this case I would put options to js object and modify it with $.extend. Or if you want to modify doom you may easily do it with $(selector).html() or js replace.